# GraphicsMagick not listed in installed packages after install from source

Tags: installation, install-from-source

I've installed GraphicsMagick following the [instructions on the website](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html), and ran the build verifications it says, and though I'm not sure if those were to verify that install was successful or not, but at I guess at least having terminal to recognize the gm command means it was successfully installed, and besides I found a GraphicsMagick directory in my `/usr/local/include`, again I don't know if that proves anything. But when I list the installed packages with dpkg -l it's not there.

Now, I need to install Octave and I wonder if it will install GraphicksMagick again, which is something I don't want it to do if it ever would. Besides I am now unable to remove it using apt-get remove. So how can I know what's wrong with my installation and if installing Octave will install its own version of GM?

Comment: Have you tried other programs like this on from the Software Centre?

Comment: I've tried it now, and it's a known bug, graphicksmagick as in the repository results in warnings with Octave. Had to rebuild it, an don't know how really. It's been like three days that I'm into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you installed from source and did not install a debian package, so therefore dpkg would have no knowledge of it.

Comment: So there is not a way to make it recognize that package? And if a package has it as its dependencies, would it still try to install it? How can I fix that?

Comment: Install the deb package instead, no? Or at least, if you want to test your skills debianize the package. Either way if you don't understand the package system you would better stick to the apt system.

Comment: You would have to build a package of it. But it is already packaged in Ubuntu, so there is generally no need to install it yourself or build your own packages.

Comment: Well I need GM with special configurations, that's why I installed from source. I didn't give the deb package a try, but I thought it woulndn't give me that option. I try that.